# Generating Remote Control Events from my app

Tags: ios, uievent

I have two questions regarding Remote Control Events on iOS:

1. I know that music applications are registered to remote control events and then can receive such events from the iPhone's player widget. 
   **Let's say I want my app to fire such events, is that possible?**
2. How does headphones for example generate those events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without private API, you cannot send remotecontrol event to your application.

The reason is we cannot create such an Event (UIEvent) to send out by using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendEvent:anEvent];
```

You can, however save a registered event then play back by calling the above-function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it possible for headphone events but with private API, you can send some events like: home button press, power button press or mouse events (not tested).

You should read this book:

> [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1118057651/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_1?pf_rd_p=1535523702&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=0321278542&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=0T2AMHJCEEKJN41YJHD5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118057651)

It'll be a hard work to make this works.

Take a look at GSEvent to know how to send an event to OS (iOS).

Edit: I've found 2 event types in GSEvent.GSEventType:

```
kGSEventHeadsetButtonDown = 1018,
kGSEventHeadsetButtonUp = 1019,
```

PS: - this use private API so it will be rejected if you post this app to AppStore.

Comment: Private APIs can't help me. Thanks.